# Почему программа на c++ работает без указания пространства имен для некоторых функций

Tags: c++, namespace

Почему необходимо указывать пространство имен для cin и endl, но необязательно для srand и time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int main() {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int randomNumber = rand() % 6 + 1;
    std::cout << randomNumber << ", " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно написать `cout << randomNumber << ", " << endl;` ничего не изменится, ошибок не будет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, с чего бы не будет? Не скомпилируется же.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ideone.com/3ziP3G   разве?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так там же `using namespace std;`, а у автора вопроса нет. Вот, убираем `std::` и не компилируется: https://ideone.com/lUzi8N.

Comment: @maggieeagle, если имя не находится в   наименованном пространстве имен, то  указывать не на что...

Comment: @Qwertiy точно. привык уже к ним)

Comment: Поняла, спасибо. Почему тогда если указать, например, std::time() работать все равно будет?

Comment: 1) Указывать пространство имён `std` для функций `srand`, `rand` и `time` необходимо, т.к. именно в этом пространстве имён они объявлены.

Comment: 2) Код _может_ работать без указания пространства имён, т.к. любое объявление из `std` также может быть объявлено в глобальной области видимости. [headers/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/headers#5): ... In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope of the namespace `std`. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У всех хедеров, доставшихся по наследству из C (напр. `<cstdlib>`, `<ctime>`), есть по две версии: `<c??>` и `<??.h>`, например `<ctime>` и `<time.h>`.

`<c??>` объявляют имена в пространстве имен `std`.

`<??.h>` объявляют имена в глобальном пространстве имен.

Но обоим вариантам [разрешается объявлять имена и там и там](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers), что и произошло в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что унаследованные из си функции доступны в глобальном пространстве имён.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работает в безымянном пространстве имён `::`. Функции `srand` и `time` объявлены там-же. Потоки в `<iostream>` объявлены в другом пространстве имён `std`, и чтобы использовать функции из другого пространства нужно так писать `std :: cout`.

Comment: В сtime указано следующее:

```namespace std
{
  using ::clock_t;
  using ::time_t;
  using ::tm;

  using ::clock;
  using ::difftime;
  using ::mktime;
  using ::time;
  using ::asctime;
  using ::ctime;
  using ::gmtime;
  using ::localtime;
  using ::strftime;
}```

Получается, что в std.

Comment: @maggieeagle, ничего подобного, using лишь позволяет определить такое же имя в пространстве имён для того чтобы оно было доступно в нем . Там же стоит 2 двоеточия, что говорит о глобальном пространстве имён, если быть точнее то анонимным.

Comment: команда `using ::..` помогает искать определения функции в безымянном пространстве, когда код исполняется в пространстве `std`. Вы можете точно так-же добавить у себя команду `using std :: cout ;` и тогда можно уже использовать прямо `cout << ..`

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете библиотеки, которые предназначены для си, но притом для совместимости, эти же библиотеки можно использовать и в с++. В си нет никаких пространств имён, классов и т.п. поэтому при обращении к си функциям, вам нет необходимости писать что либо перед именем функций.

В то время, как в стандартной библиотеке с++ есть такие заголовочные файлы которые начинаются на `c...`, исключением являются лишь некоторые из, все они предназначены для си, но так же доступны в с++ для совместимости.

Пишите на с++? Используйте библиотеки предназначеные именно для него.

---

Для того чтобы вы поняли о чем идёт речь, смотрите, я напишу свое пространство имён, и скажу, что у меня там есть класс строки:

```
#include <string>
namespace ori {
    using string = ::std::string;
};
```

Теперь я могу писать код без использования пространства имён ::std::... И обращаться только в свое пространство имён ori.

`::ori::string str;`

На самом же деле, это просто алиас для класса из стандартной библиотеки.